# Unable to avoid default warning on 'onbeforeunload' event

Tags: javascript, html, onbeforeunload

I'm working on a webpage and need to hit a `disconnect` request to the server before closing the window, so I'm using the `onbeforeunload` event to do this.
However, no matter how much I try, I can't seem to be able to avoid the default 'Save changes' dialog that apppears when using `onbeforeunload`.

Am I missing something? Why does the dialog still appear?

```js
async function close(event){
  // Prevent default warning
  event.preventDefault();
  event.returnValue = null;
  
  // Here goes my stuff. There's an await here.
  
  // More preventing
  return null;
}

// The event is set later
window.onbeforeunload = close;
```

Thank you.

Comment: The documentation for [beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload) warns that browsers are not all implementing it in the same way. Which browser are you using? Have you tried with more than one browser?

Comment: @focorner I'm using the latest version of Chromium. Of course I want Chrome to work as It's the most used browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of the `onbeforeunload` event is used as a mean to tell the browser to show a warning message (historically, it could be a custom one).

Your `async` function returns a Promise, so the browser thinks that it should show this warning message (you'd probably see the message `[object Promise]` in a browser that still does accept custom messages).

```js
async function foo() {
  return "hello";
}

console.log(foo().toString()); // [object Promise]
```

To avoid this, do not use an `async` function here. By the time your asynchronous tasks will have ended, there are big chances that the page will have been closed anyway.

Also, note that you can not prevent an `onbeforeunload` event. Only the user can (by the aforementioned warning message prompt).

And finally, if you wish to send data in this event, then use the [`navigator.sendBeacon()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) method, which should be able to work even after the page has been closed.

Ps: generally don't use `async` functions as event callbacks, moreover when you wish to prevent their default behavior.

Comment: Had to make my server accept POST requests as fake GET ones because sendBeacon just sends POST requests, but else it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think it 's not possible because it' s about protection
  We can enable any site designer to make the client can not get out of his site

Comment: In fact I accidentally created a bug in at which I completely blocked the user from refreshing, closing or anyway unloading the page.